# Recommended way to name and organize sub-components (sub-folders) in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, directory-structure

Say I am building a page that displays the user profile/settings page. It might have components for the profile, a profile photo, a bio section, etc...

I currently have the following structure

```
components/
    |- profile/
        |- profile.jsx
        |- profile_photo/
            |- profile_photo.jsx
            |- edit_button.jsx
            |- edit_modal.jsx
        |- user_bio/
          |- user_bio.jsx
          |- education.jsx
          |- demographics.jsx
```

Is there a community recommended way to organize and name these files?

1. Right now the path feels redundant because I call `components/profile/profile.jsx` or `components/profile/user_bio/user_bio.jsx`. Should the "main file" under each subdirectory be named the same as the folder or be named something generic like `index.jsx`? Or is the redundancy just accepted?
2. Where do tests go? Are they placed in the same folder as the files (like Golang's standard) or are they placed in a separate top-level `tests/` directory (like Ruby on Rails projects).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `index.js` file and export the file. Let's take the `profile` component as an example. The `index.js` file would look like this:

```
export {default} from "./profile"
```

So you only have to import it with `components/profile` instead of `components/profile/profile.js`

Comment: Does importing `components/profile` automatically look for a `components/profile/index.js`? And if so, will it still work if the extension is `index.jsx` ?

Comment: @user2490003 yes and yes

Answer (score 7):

There are different approaches to structure of the react projects

React recommendations is https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html

You can also read this:

https://daveceddia.com/react-project-structure/

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-structure-your-react-app-98c48e102aad

I would say that grouping by features works best for big projects and grouping by file type is better for small projects.