# React best practice: component in separate file or component in separate folder with located in index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-component

I am not sure where to find info about folder/file naming conventions so, I'm going to post it here, hoping this question will make sense. In my previous job I came across two component naming options (used for building components / sub-components / etc in a *React* project).

## Options:

### Option A:

```
.
├── components/
│   └── SubComponent/
│       ├── SubComponent.js → // export default function SubComponent(){ return <></> }
│       └── index.js → // export { default } from './SubComponent'
└── App.js → // import SubComponent from './components/SubComponent'
```

### Option B:

```
.
├── components/
│   └── RandomSubFolder/
│       └── ComponentName.js → // export default function ComponentName(){ return <></> }
└── App.js // import ComponentName from './components/RandomSubFolder/ComponentName'
```

### To Sum Up:

In both cases we are talking about a large number of components, sub-components, sub-sub-components and so on.

I know `index.js` ( which allows a simple *import* based on its parent *foldername* ) adds noise but is it the case that **Option A** is preferred for its simplicity despite this or **Option B** ( which relies of *filename* )?

Comment: I would go for logical grouping of files keeping scalability in mind.

Comment: **option A** is the obvious choice. try to separate your code  (modular) as much as you can. i'll add one more point here. name your module on based on the component . `components folder  / --> subComponents.js` doesn't make any sense. have a proper naming convention for your sub-components too

Comment: I think this can't be answered so that's true in all cases. Some links: - [React about folder structure](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html)
- [Node.js "Folders as Modules"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)
- [recommended-way-to-name-and-organize-sub-components-sub-folders-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893652/recommended-way-to-name-and-organize-sub-components-sub-folders-in-react)
- [bradfrost "component names"](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/this-or-that-component-names-index-js-or-component-js/)